# Can I have onmouseover titles in both sides of my over selection?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using onmouseover to over a precise section of my background image and I have the respective title for it. What I am trying to achieve is to have two titles on my over selection one in left side and the other on the right side, is that possible ? I have tried to add span and style it but with no success this is because my programming skills still very poor.

Bellow is the code that I have been working on:

[Here is the code on :  jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nfsarmento/hbn0g63m/7/)

```
<div style="position:relative; margin-top:25px; background-
image:url(http://nuno-sarmento.com/books.png); width:640px; height:82px;">

<a href="#" style="display:block;  position:absolute; height:70px; 
width:175px; top:0px; left:220px; overflow:hidden;" 
onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor=' rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)';" title="1960
to 1970" 
onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='';"></a>  


<a href="#" style="display:block;  position:absolute; height:74px;
width:175px; top:0px; left:20px; overflow:hidden;"   
onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor=' rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)';" title="1970 to
1980" 
onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='';"></a>  


<a href="#" style="display:block;  position:absolute; height:74px;
width:175px; top:0px; left:420px; overflow:hidden;" 
onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor=' rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)';" title="1990 to 
2000" 
onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='';"></a>        

</div>
```

Image sketch for what I am trying to achieve

[image]

Comment: The JSFidlle and the code you provide don't match...?

Comment: @LinkinTED Sorry I going to change it now, thank for let me know.

Comment: @LinkinTED has been changed now

Comment: Can you provide a sketch of the desired result?

Comment: @LinkinTED - Thank you for replying back, I will update my question with image sketch

Comment: @LinkinTED - I have now upload the image sketch .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with some JQuery too:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $( 'a' ).mouseout(function(){
    $('.info_span1').hide();$('.info_span2').hide();
  });
  
    $('a').mouseenter(function(){
        var position = $(this).position();
        $(".info_span1").show();$(".info_span2").show();
        $(".info_span1").text($(this).data("title1"));
        $(".info_span2").text($(this).data("title2"));
        $(".info_span1").css({top: $(this).height()+10, left:position.left, position:'absolute'});
        $(".info_span2").css({top: $(this).height()+10, left:position.left+$(this).width()-60, position:'absolute'});
       
    });
});
```

```css
.info_span1 .info_span2{
    display:none;
  text-align:center;
}



.info_span2{
  display:none;
  width:50px;
  left: auto;
  right: 0; 
        background: #ccc none repeat scroll 0 0;
    padding: 5px;
    position: absolute;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
.info_span2:after{
  left: auto;
  right: 4px; 
  border-color: transparent transparent #ccc;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 6px;
    bottom: 100%;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    margin-bottom: -1px;
}
.info_span1{
  display:none;
  width:50px;
    background:#ccc;
    padding: 5px;
    position: absolute;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
.info_span1:after{
    border-color: transparent transparent #ccc;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 6px;
    bottom: 100%;
    content: "";
    left: 4px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-bottom: -1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="position:relative; margin-top:25px; background-image:url(http://nuno-sarmento.com/books.png); width:640px; height:82px;">
    <span class="info_span1"></span>
    <span class="info_span2"></span>
 
    

<a href="#" style="display:block;  position:absolute; height:75px; width:175px; top:0px; left:20px; overflow:hidden;" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor=' rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)';" data-title1="1960" data-title2="1970"
onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='';"></a>
  
  <a href="#" style="display:block;  position:absolute; height:75px; width:175px; top:0px; left:220px; overflow:hidden;" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor=' rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)';" data-title1="1970" data-title2="1980"   
onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='';"></a>  
  
    

 <a href="#" style="display:block;  position:absolute; height:75px; width:175px; top:0px; left:420px; overflow:hidden;" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor=' rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)';" data-title1="1990" data-title2="2000" 
onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='';"></a>        
    
    <p></p>    
    
</div>
```

Comment: I really appreciate you help and your fast response . Your code is almost full working the problem with your code is when the mouse goes out from the hover selection the title stays and it doesn't disappear  ... any ideas?

Comment: Yes you can add `mouseout()`  event and hide the required elements: see updated answer

Comment: You are amazing big thank you one more question...pleaseee, is there any way to style it ?

Comment: see update style is inspired from `LinkinTED` answer

Comment: Brilliant you are genius .

Comment: Hi Armani I thought I had this done, but now I got a problem with this ...you may be able to help me please.  The idea was to have  a pile of books all laid down where I can over with the mouse and I see when the books were read. The code above works perfect in only one book but if I try to apply to the next book row it will be a mess with code.  I was planing to have about 50 books. Do you now any better solution for it ? Thank you

Comment: can you provide the complete HTML in a fiddle ??cause the code have to work if only you gives the riegth classes names in your html

Comment: Hi Armani thank you for replying, here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nfsarmento/1m1sg2L1/5/

Comment: right now on this fiddle has only have 2 books but I am pretending to have more 20 books

Comment: you dont have to duplicate the JQuery code , your html code can have also the same structure and same classes names I 've added hier an id for each book, depending on the book id your hovering you  can hide or show your info spans --> http://jsfiddle.net/1m1sg2L1/6/

Comment: that is brilliant, I never going to be a programmer :(  miles way form this kind of knowledge ..thank you again

Comment: everybody starts from scratch you will achieve what you want if you really want it. glad that this works for you :)...If you are interested to learn jquery you can start from here :http://jquery.com/

Comment: Thank you for kind words :) . there is any way to make this responsive ?

Comment: didnt get what do you mean

Comment: I mean making this code mobile friendly - responsive

Comment: Sorry for taking your time do you have any ideias regarding making this code responsive

Comment: I guess you could easy fix this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31835128/jquery-onmouseover-selection-attribute/31835344#31835344

Answer (score 1):

With your code it's hard to accomplish that. The title attribute is styled by the browser, and can't be influenced.

But I made you this alternative:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: boder-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#main {
  width: 640px;
  height: 82px;
  background-image: url(http://nuno-sarmento.com/books.png)
}
#main>div {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  height: 100%;
}
#main>div p {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  margin-top: 6px;
  padding: 5px;
  background: lightblue;
}
#main>div p:first-child {
  left: 0;
}
#main>div p:last-child {
  right: 0;
}
#main>div:hover {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
#main>div:hover p {
  display: block;
}
#main>div p:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 0;
  border: 6px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: lightblue;
}
#main>div p:last-child:after {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
    <div>
        <p>1960</p> <p>1670</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>1970</p> <p>1680</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>1990</p> <p>2000</p>
    </div> 
</div>
```

You might need to adjust the widths of the div. The "tooltips" will automatically move with them.

Comment: I really appreciate you help and your fast response . Your code looks amazing the only problem that I may have is to pass this to my wordpress. With the previous code I was able to stack visual composer rows with my book background images and add the html code in every single VC row .

Comment: I end up to use your code . I am really sorry for not accepting your solution as the correct one .  Thank you very much spending your time in helping me .

Comment: @CabLondon, you can undo the acceptation, and check another answer... just unselect it, and select another one :)

Comment: your code is good but I just found out that is not going to work on responsive :(